# Get length of a string in label widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

Is there a way to get the length of the string of characters in a label widget in Tkinter? I'm trying to update the value of a label with a button press, and my first check is to see if there is something in the label. The basics of what I'm trying to do is as follows

```
if len(label_widget) > 0:
    do something....
else:
    do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cget` method lets you get the value of any of the configured options.

For example:

```
if len(label_widget.cget("text")) > 0:
    ...
```

Comment: Is the `"text"` portion an argument passed into the `cget`? Or what does it do?

Comment: It is the name of a configuration option. When you configure an option  you do something like `Label(..., text="hello")`. When you want to get the configuration option, you specify the name as a string `the_label.cget("text")`